# Can I allow raw unicode in HTTP headers using NSUrlSession?

Tags: c#, ios, unicode, xamarin, nsurlsession

I'm constructing an NSUrlSession as follows:

```
NSUrlSessionConfiguration sessionCfg = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration("mySpecialSessionName");
NSUrlSessionDelegate sessionDelegate = new MySessionDelegate();
urlSession = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(sessionCfg, sessionDelegate, NSOperationQueue.MainQueue);
```

And invoking background downloads with custom HTTP headers:

```
NSMutableUrlRequest mutableRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest();
mutableRequest.HttpMethod = "POST";
mutableRequest.Url = NSUrl.FromString(someEndpoint);
mutableRequest["MyCustomHeader"] = someStringWithUnicodeChars;
mutableRequest.Body = NSData.FromString(somePostBody);

NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask = m_UrlSession.CreateDownloadTask(mutableRequest);
downloadTask.Resume();
```

However, the header value string seems to get truncated at the first character above 255. For example, the header value:

```
SupeЯ Σario Bros
```

is received by the server as

```
Supe
```

When instead using .NET HttpClient on xamarin, unicode header strings successfully make it to the server unmodified. However, I'd like to make use of NSUrlSession's background downloading feature.

(I realize that support of unicode in HTTP headers is hit-and-miss, but since the HTTP server in this case is a particular custom server that doesn't currently support things like base64 encoding, passing the raw string is desired)

Comment: Interestingly, I tried some javascript code on Safari to send an ajax request with such a header, and it resulted in the same truncation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you'll be able to make that work, but two things come to mind:

- What you have here is equivalent to calling setValue:forKey: on the URL request.  I don't think that will do what you're expecting.  Try calling the setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: method instead.
- Try specifying the encoding before you specify your custom header value, e.g. [theRequest setValue:@"...; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

If neither of those helps, you'll probably have to encode the data in some way.  I would suggest using URL encoding, because that's a lot simpler to implement on the server side than Base64.  For the iOS side, see this link for info on how to URL-encode a string:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21938/looking-for-this-method-void-setvalue-nsstring-value-forhttpheaderfield-nsstring-field says "The setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: selector is mapped to the indexer of NSMutableUrlRequest", i.e. the bracket operator. So I believe I'm already following your first bullet.

Comment: Could be, but for some reason, in the back of my mind, I was thinking that there were some edge cases that behaved differently.  I may be wrong.

Comment: Setting "Content-Type" header to "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8" right before setting the other headers didn't seem to help.